# Transactions and form api

Tags: 7, forms, database

Is it possible to use FAPI and transactions?

I need to implement a validation that makes a query to check something and on the submit I need to update the database.

I thought to open a transaction on the validation callback and set it on the $form_state and then commit my transaction on the submit handler. I didn't liked this solution but was the best that I could think.

How do you solve this kind of things on drupal? What do you think about my solution?

Answer (score 2):

Can you use FAPI with transactions: Yes.

But you can't or rather shouldn't use it the way you describe. Transactions only take effect when you commit them, so there really is no point in starting the transaction in the validation. Also what happens if you have a validation error, you won't commit the transaction. I believe that starting a transaction will effect other incoming queries as well.

Transactions are only good if you want to do multiple queries at once, and do all or nothing. Like insert data in main table and revision table and then update the revision number in main table.

What are you trying to do that makes you think that you should make transaction in such a way?

Comment: I need to check if someone has already used a code on the validation handler and then on the submit handler I need to mark the code as used. How you you do that using FAPI?

Comment: @LuizGuilherme There is a huge difference between using code that interacts with each other on the validation and submit handler and opening a SQL transaction which effectively blocks all incoming queries until the transaction is committed. You should use $form_state to send info from validate to submit handler.